# Не срабатывает с первого раза removeClass jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой код: http://jsfiddle.net/h754k/

```js
$("#metro-map1 span").on('click', function(e) {

  $('.clear-list').show();
  var id = $(this).attr('class');
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  var val = id.split("s");


  if ($(this).hasClass("selectedPoint")) {
    alert('rr');

    $(this).removeClass('selectedPoint'); //Attention
    $('#hidden_' + id).remove();
    $('#metros_' + id).remove();
    $('.rcb ul li').last().remove();
    $('.search_metro_form li').last().remove();
    $(this).next('div').removeClass('selectedPointDiv'); //Attention

  } else {
    $('.rcb ul').append('<li rel="' + id + '">' + title + '</li>');
    $(this).next('div').addClass('selectedPointDiv'); //Attention
    $('.search_metro_form').append('<li rel="' + id + '">' + title + '</li>');
    $(this).attr('rel', id);
    $('.t_green_small').show();
    $(this).addClass('selectedPoint'); //Attention 
    $('#selected').append('<input type="hidden" id="hidden_' + val[1] + '" name="metro[]" value="' + val[1] + '" />');
    $('#search_form').append('<input type="hidden" id="metros_' + val[1] + '" name="metro_s[]" value="' + val[1] + '" />');
  }



});


$("#metro-map1 div").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.clear-list').show();
  var id = $(this).attr('class');
  var title = $(this).attr('title');
  var val = id.split("s");


  if ($(this).hasClass("selectedPointDiv")) {
    $(this).removeClass('selectedPointDiv'); //Attention $('#hidden_'+id).remove();
    $('#metros_' + id).remove();
    $('.search_metro_form li').last().remove();
    $('.rcb ul li').last().remove();
    $(this).next('div').removeClass('selectedPoint'); // Attention


  } else {
    $('.rcb ul').append('<li rel="' + id + '">' + title + '</li>');
    $('.search_metro_form').append('<li rel="' + id + '">' + title + '</li>');
    $('.t_green_small').show();
    $(this).attr('rel', id);
    $(this).addClass('selectedPointDiv'); //Attention 
    $('#selected').append('<input type="hidden" id="hidden_' + val[1] + '" name="metro[]" value="' + val[1] + '" />');
    $('#search_form').append('<input type="hidden" id="metros_' + val[1] + '" name="metro_s[]" value="' + val[1] + '" />');
    $(this).prev('span').addClass('selectedPoint'); //Attention

  }



});
```

```html
<span style="background-image: url(/images/stations-sprite.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: -1000px -1000px; cursor: pointer; display: block; position: absolute; left: 315px; top: 44px; width: 9px; height: 9px;" title="Владыкино"
class="s250"><img src="/pic/design/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1"></span>

<div style="background-image: url(/images/stations-sprite.gif); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: -1000px -1000px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; left: 324px; top: 44px; height: 9px; width: 49px;" title="Владыкино" class="s250"
id="s250-126">
  <img src="/pic/design/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1">
</div>
```

Когда происходит клик по элементу `span`, ему назначается класс `selectedPoint`.

При повторном клике на этот элемент, класс должен удаляться, но почему-то это срабатывает только после второго клика на элемент.

Comment: изначально у него же нет класса selectedPoint, поэтому первый клик назначает ему его, а второй снимает. И далее, через одного. Всё в порядке, вроде бы ([скриншот](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ew71tmmjd41na5v/Screenshot%202014-02-28%2013.08.37.png), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/h754k/1/))

Comment: Когда уже произошел клик - ему назначился класс и после класс убирается со 2 клика. Т-е такой класс уже существует

Comment: Esti drugie predpolojeniya?

Comment: сделайте ваш fiddle рабочим, не просто код а демонстрирующим проблему.